# How to automatically run user-code upon loading Fortran module

Tags: c, gcc, fortran, gfortran

In C using GCC, one can use the following function to have some code called upon loading a shared library:

```
static void __attribute__((constructor)) _my_initializer(void)
{
    ...
}
```

After some search on the web, I could not find the equivalent in Fortran using GCC (i.e. gfortran). For sure that this feature must exist in gfortran since it comes from GCC (thus it should be available in all languages supported by GCC). Any pointers?

Answer (score 5):

*"For sure that this feature must exist in gfortran since it comes from GCC"* That is clearly false. It simply does not have to exist. gfortran does support the `!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES` directive, but the number of attributes supported is limited.

You can write your constructor in C and let it be part of the same library and call any Fortran code you want.

Example:

library.f90:

```
subroutine sub() bind(C)
 write(*,*) "Hello!"
end subroutine
```

init_library.c:

```
void sub(void);
static void __attribute__((constructor)) _init(void)
{
    sub();
}
```

load_library.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
typedef void (*foo)(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    void *lib = dlopen("library.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if(lib == NULL)
        return printf("ERROR: Cannot load library\n");
    dlclose(lib);
}
```

compile and run:

```
> gfortran -c -fPIC init_library.c
> gfortran -c -fPIC library.f90
> gfortran -shared library.o init_library.o -o library.so
> gfortran load_library.c -ldl
> ./a.out 
 Hello!
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code @Vladimir F! Is it possible to have just Fortran code and still achieve a way to call some Fortran code when users import the module?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: Can you get away with just writing the prototype in C and then writing the actual subroutine in Fortran? In Windows you would just write a Fortran DllMain.

Comment: No, the Fortran compiler does not look at any C prototypes when compiling a Fortran procedure.

Comment: In principle, you could edit the object file and add the Fortran procedure to the constructors list, but this is certainly a lot more troublesome than just having a small C wrapper.